# Infinitely many solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\cos \sqrt z=z$ has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.

Now, the thing comes to my mind is to prove it using the Hadamard theorem which is about the growth order. But I do not want to use such a theorem to solve this problem even if it works. Next, I noticed that we cannot also use the Rouche theorem because cos is not a polynomial, maybe there is a trick that would turn it into a problem which can be solved by Rouche theorem. Any hint would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Do you know what is Great Picard's theorem?

Comment: So, you want to say that $\frac{cos(\sqrt{z}}{z}$ has an essential singularity at zero? @CalvinLin

Comment: It might be slightly easier to show that $\cos z=z^2$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: How would that be easier? Would you explain a bit more? @VarunVejalla

Comment: I think you are meaning that we should consider $\frac{z}{cos(\sqrt{z}}$ and then zero is the essential singularity of it. But how do we know that one is not that exception point in Great Picard's Theorem? @CalvinLin

Comment: @John I'm not sure, but it just looked nicer to work with than $\cos\sqrt{z}=z$. Sorry - might have made it seem like I knew for sure that it was easier.

Comment: @John Show that there is at least one solution by MVT on the real interval [0,1]. For $f(z) = \cos \sqrt{z} - z$, $f(0) = 1, f(1) < 0 $. $\quad$ Alternatively, (with much more firepower), for Great Picard to miss a point, the order must be an integer. In this case, $f(z)$ has order 1/2, so it hits every point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motivated by the comments of Calvin Lin, a solution can be formulated as below:
Consider $f(z)=\cos\sqrt z -z=0$. Then $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<0$ tells that $f(z)=0$ in the interval $(0,1)$ atleast once and hence $\cos\sqrt z=z$ has atleast one solution. 
Further, rewrite $f(z)=0$ as $g(z)=1$ where $g(z)=\frac{\cos\sqrt z}{z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. By Picard's great theorem, range of  $g(z)$ must assume every value in complex plane infinitely often so $g(z)=1$ must be acheived for infinite values of $z$ just in the vicinity of singularity $z=0$.

> Note that the possibility of an exception in range of $g(z)$ has already been ruled out by MVT in first paragraph.

Comment: I got it, have a question though. The reason that we say zero is an essential singularity is that when we multiply by zero, we have that $cos(\sqrt{z})$ is not holomorphic at zero? @NitinUniyal

Comment: @John... Precisely stating what you meant is that you cannot remove the singularity of $f(z)$ even by multiplying it by $z^r$ for some $r\in\mathbb Z^+$. Or simply, expand $f(z)$ in powers of $z$ to see the infinite terms containing negative powers of $z$.

Comment: I am sorry you are right; I was meaning that when we multiply be z not zero. I got it, thanks! @NitinUniyal

Comment: @John...My pleasure to help you!